# Why JS event "onclick" work out after second click but, not first? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Can some one tell me, Why tag `a` make my first click without opening the table, but take the address which should go (in first moment table is hidden) [image: first click]

And after second click, table is opening and I'm going to it. Without tag `<a href="#team-@team.Id">` it open by 1 click.

`#team-**@team.Id**` - it's normal, i did 15 tables by cycle, and make for each table id)

My code in view

```
<div id=team-logo-wrapper>
<ul>
    @foreach (Team team in Model.Item2)
    {
        <li>
            <div class="team-section-box">
                <p class="team-name">@team.Name</p>
                <a href="#team-@team.Id">
                    <img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/{0}", team.Path))" class="logo-images" alt="Логотип @team.Name" title="Логотип @team.Name" onclick="ShowTable(@team.Id)" />
                </a>

            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

in CSS my display and visibility

```
.table-hidden {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

the simplest script

```
var flag = true;
function ShowTable(teamId) {
    var id = "team-" + teamId;
    var getElem = document.getElementById(id);

    if (flag) {
        flag = false;
        getElem.style.display = 'none';
        getElem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    else {
        flag = true;
        getElem.style.display = 'block';
        getElem.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want show  table on first click?

Comment: yes, and after click go to table

Comment: I think the problem is flag variable which is default value is true.

Comment: yor are right, thank you!!!(don't know, why i did't think about flag!)

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the image, you also activate the link.

If you really need the link, then change it to something like:

```
<a  href="javascript: void(0)">
  <img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/{0}", team.Path))" 
       class="logo-images" alt="Логотип @team.Name" 
       title="Логотип @team.Name" 
       onclick="ShowTable(@team.Id)" />
 </a>
```

Comment: it helpes, but I have on quastion, if i have 5 tables, open first by 1 click(good), and i want open second table too(dont close first). It openes by second click, why?
(if open than close , and next table work right)